# function reminding me about a date

Tags: javascript

I have a function and it represent a date that is 2 weeks off from start date, counted by each passing Thursday, but excludes the Thursday of the week the date was made.

```
function GetThursdayIn2Weeks(date)
{
    var day = date.getDay();

    // Add 2 weeks.
    var newDate = new Date(date.setTime(date.getTime() + (14 * 86400000)));

    // Adjust for Thursday.
    var adjust = 4 - day;
    if (adjust <= 0) // Might need to be changed - See comments!
      adjust +=7;

    // Apply Thursday adjustment.
    newDate = new Date(newDate.setTime(newDate.getTime() + (adjust * 86400000)));

    return newDate;    
}
```

How would I make this set off a different function every day that passed, starting a week after the beginning of the process, remind me about the due date coming up, but before the end of the date of the process?

Comment: Will the javascript stay loaded during the whole duration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` to execute a reminder after a set time. However, the problem is that your javascript environment will probably not keep running for such long times, be it node.js or your browser.

I would suggest those mechanisms :

- store your target date in localstorage after calculating it with your given code
- define a function that will use `setTimeout()` to define the next occurrence of the reminder for a given target date
- when the page is loaded, use that function for each date stored in the localstorage
- when a date is added to the localstorage, or a given target date reachs one of its reminders, call the function for this specific date

The mentioned function should set a timer for the first day that is at the same time greater than the current date, greater than the day 1 week before the target date, and lower than the target date.

Here is an 'hopefully) working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qsxtc7y/).

Comment: 'when the page is loaded, use that function for each date stored in the localstorage' how would i do this?

Would I use? 

var myDate = new Date(parseInt(localStorage['key'], 10));

Comment: is this the right approach? 

var now = new Date();
var millisTill10 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 10, 0, 0, 0) - now;
if (millisTill10 < 0) {
     millisTill10 += 86400000; // it's after 10am, try 10am tomorrow.
}
setTimeout(function(){alert("It's 10am!")}, millisTill10);

Comment: @joe222 sorry just came back ; I'll try to answer your questions and post some example code

Comment: @joe222 So about the localStorage : you can use it to persist your date(s) so they can still be retrieved after a reload. To do so, use localStorage.setItem(key, data) to store the date(s) when they are created, and localStorage.getItem(key) to retrieve it/them when needed. localStorage only stores Strings, so you will need to recreate a date from its string representation. Furthermore, if you want to store an array of dates, you will need to serialize the array using JSON.stringify(date) when storing and deserialize it using JSON.parse(data).

Comment: @joe222 your use of setTimeout looks correct. You could use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library to make handling dates easier

Comment: I would like to do it with out monent.js.

Comment: thus fare I have done the first part via...
localStorage['key'] = ''+day.getTime(); // code To store a date in localStorage

Comment: and the third part is now... => 
var myDate = new Date(parseInt(localStorage['date'], 10))
var d = JSON.stringify(myDate);

Comment: Is this right, relative to the function for the first part? I corrected the 'key'  => localStorage['date'] = ''+day.getTime(); // code To store a date in localStorage

Comment: oh, and as to your monent.js... question, no , i would like it to be free of monent.js

Comment: as for the second part, this is what i have thus fare...=>


 
 var timeOfNote = function surprise(cb) { (function loop() { var now = new Date(); if (now.getDate() === 12 && now.getHours() === 12 && now.getMinutes() === 0) { cb(); } now = new Date(); // allow for time passing var delay = 86400000 - (now % 86400000); // exact ms to next minute interval setTimeout(loop, delay); })(); }

Comment: in the case which i have, I do not think an is needed. what would be an advantage of using an array?

Comment: following you guide... the storage would look like..localStorage.setItem(key, data) = day.getTime();

Comment: That makes a lot of unformatted code, could you maybe make a JSFiddle? For the localStorage if you only have a single date, the following should be enough : to save `localStorage.setItem("date", myDate)` ; to retrieve `var myDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("date"))`

Comment: i think this code is correnct.... can you check it?


 function surprise(cb) {
    (function loop() {
        var now = new Date();
        if (now.getDate() === 12 && now.getHours() === 12 && now.getMinutes() === 0) {
            cb();
        }
        now = new Date(); // allow for time passing
        var delay = 86400000 - (now % 86400000); // exact ms to next minute interval
        setTimeout(loop, delay);
    })();
}

oh, and the fiddler ... it will not let me make an account...??

Comment: you don't need an account to use and export a JSFiddle, saving your code gives you an url to share. About your code, what is cb supposed to be? also, you have no loop variable, the setTimeout won't work that way

Comment: oh, ok. well the code would not run in JSFiddle, or i did not give it the proper variables to run... the cd was just a random variable that i was thinking of using... i think i need to start from scratch... with this part... can you help?

Comment: do you have any ideas as how to do point 2, --define a function that will use setTimeout() to define the next occurrence of the reminder for a given target date-- please guide me... I also do not know how to do point 3, --when the page is loaded, use that function for each date stored in the localstorage-- i thought that it was just to load the stored value but it now seems to be more involved... pleas help.

Comment: @joe222 I added a JSFiddle with all that